# Determining if the App is running locally or has been deployed through the App Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

Is there a way to determine if the App is running locally or has been deployed through the App Store?

I would like to test the trial mode functionality using Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator during development but default to Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp if the app has been downloaded from the store by a regular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is easy to do. I suspect the *easiest* way is through conditional compliation, and produce a specific build for submission. You can use [Ajaxmin](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com) for this, but that would require a little bit of setting up.

Given that an application when deployed is supposed to be in distinguishable no matter it's mechanism, I don't think this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx

Will help. It will plausibly tell you if you've been deployed from VS (which deploys loose files), rather than as a package.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; this won't help? Wouldn't checking if "Debug" existed in the path work (`installedLocation.path.indexOf`), even as a poor man's check?

Comment: As I said, that'll tell you if it's been deployed through *vs*, but not if someone has add-appxpackage'd your compiled appx on some dev-license enabled machine.